# How to authenticate a mobile ADF application

Tags: java, iis, mobile, basic-authentication, oracle-adf

How can I authenticate a user onto IIS. Actually my purpose is that an online user to make supply enter the application by using a kind of verification. And on the other hand we have Microsoft web system. So probably, I need to solve the authentication issue on IIS. Essentially I know how to secure and authentication AMX page within weblogic system. Basic HTTP Authentication is a standard though and ADF mobile useS it too. But can it handle my expectation, I cannot be sure.

What is the best practice and best way?

Answer (score 0):

This is acutally a question to the IIS guys - all you need is a URL on that server that will prompt you for a basic authentication.